# Stuck With A Pull data Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

Im banging my head on the wall for the past 3 hours trying to figure out How can solve this issue.

Iv managed to make a formula that pulls specific data that iv specified. in my ex:

All the people who has 2 days left and are in "On hold" status (see table for reference).

```
=QUERY(data,"select D where A contains 'on hold' and E<=2",0)
```

1.the issue is that iv managed to create that formula only by creating a cell (E) that subtracts the day difference on the dates entered (B:C).

2.how can create a subtract formula inside a query formula. please see link for detailed table.

3.Second issue is that my table is dynamic and grows with data over time. how can I make the formula to pull data from the updating cells. 
**( iv crated a name range for the table called "data" and that ranged is inside the formula)**

thanks in advance to all appreciate the help :)

[sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTl-bQhgPuoBU01qw1_n7SGpZCdoxFI6f51Hp45pqVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named ranges have a hard defined end row.  If you can use a range such as D5:F instead, you will not need to change the named range.  This range will start at cell D5 and include columns D, E, and F until the last row in the sheet.

The query needs to use datediff:

```
=QUERY(A2:E,"select D where A contains 'on hold' and datediff(C, B) <= 2",0)
```

See the [Scalar Functions portion of the Query reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions) for more.

Comment: Hey Karl_S,
Thanks a lot for the help Im going to try in Now yeppppiii :), by the where did you get the "datediff" from?
And can I make simple math inside the query?

Comment: Ignor the question found it on the link you gave me cheers bro